# What is the difference between this two arrays?

Tags: arrays, char

What is the difference between them? They shows different values when run it. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char good1[] = {'g','o','o','d'};
    char good2[] = {'g','o','o','d','\0'};
    printf("%s %s", good1,good2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: one is a c-string, the other is not.

Comment: define programming language

Answer (score 0):

`\0` is used to indicate termination character in a string.

`good1` has no termination character thus when display good1 you may get a few unwanted characters. this depends on the compiler you are using. The result may vary for different compilers.

For example,

I executed the above code in different compilers.
By using GCC-TDM C compiler, output was

`good: good:` [I added ':' in code to know the end of the string].

In paiza.io online c compiler website, the output was

`good�K��: good:`

Likewise in different compiler outputs may vary.

whereas for `good2`, since there is termination character at the end of the array, the output will be as expected.

Try to play around with `\0` you will understand the difference.

Like keep `\0` at the middle of the array and see the output.
Refer this

> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Hope this helps.

Thanks.